# How do I multiply value from column A by another value in column B, and use the results to populate column A?

Tags: python, loops

So I have the following:

```
Column A     Column B
NaN             100           
0.2              NaN
0.1              NaN
```

I need to multiply '100' (row 1) by '0.2' in row 2 of column A, and the result needs to appear in row 2 of column B. This series then needs to continue through the series (multiply row in column B by row + 1 in column A) so I get a complete set of data for column B.

I attempted the following code:

```
for i in range(len(df)-1):
       df.at[i, 'column_B] = df.at[i, 'column_B'] * df.at[i + 1, 'column_A']
```

This gives me the answer I'd expect (100*0.2), but it replaces '100' in row 1. Likewise, the rest of column B is not populated.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Store to `df.at[i + 1, 'column_B]`, not `df.at[i, 'column_B]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your question:

```
for i in range(len(df)-1):
       df.at[i+1, 'column_B'] = df.at[i, 'column_B'] * df.at[i + 1, 'column_A']
```

(just added i+1 at the start of line 2)